# How to put icons on the lock screen?

Tags: android

I need to implement an S.O.S Button. This Button should be on the lock screen of android devices. When someone clicks the S.O.S Button i need to open a special Activity which shows some Health Information about the user.

How can i set such a Button on the lock screen and run the Activity even when the screen is locked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a lock screen of my own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864300/create-a-lock-screen-of-my-own)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a lock screen widget. Look at the [`Enabling App Widgets on The Lock Screen`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen) section for more information. The restriction, however, is that it is Android 4.2 and up only.